# initialise service with observable instead of promise

Tags: angular

I want to initialise my service

```
  init(http: HttpClient): Observable<Settings> {
    console.warn('SettingsService.init');
    return http.get<Settings>('http://localhost:51829/settings')
      .pipe(tap((response: Settings) => { console.warn('this never runs'); this.settings = response; })
      );
  }
```

And in `app.module.ts`

```
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      multi: true,
      deps: [SettingsService, HttpClient],
      useFactory: (settingsService: SettingsService, http: HttpClient) => {
        return () => {
          return settingsService.init(http);
        };
      }
    },
```

But no HTTP request is made. Why isn't it working?

Comment: Sorry for the previous answer. But I can see your code works. [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ukjtxd?file=src/app/settings.service.ts)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be something to do with the value of the `useFactory` parameter.

Doing this has made it work:

```
function initializeAppFactory(settingsService: SettingsService, httpBackend: HttpBackend): () => Observable<any> {
  return () => settingsService.init(httpBackend);
}

...

useFactory: initializeAppFactory
```

It seems to have to be a separate function.